# How to fix MySQL buffer flushing not working

Tags: mysql

MySQL (5.6.17-log) server running InnoDB takes a long time to shutdown.

Because a MySQL did page cleaning at buffer when it running.

When I use command `show status like '%dirty%'` , dirty pages do not decrease per 1 second, continuously increase.

I tested another MySQL server, it flush dirty page per 1 second.

A server memory is 32GB, I use innodb_buffer_pool_size=20GB

The problem is buffer flushing is not working per 1 sec.

I tried to change my.cnf as below:

```
1) innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT -> still same problem
2) innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0 -> still same problem
3) innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 -> still same problem
4) innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 -> still same problem
5) innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 -> still same problem
```

After shutdown, dirty page increase again without flush.

How can I fixed it?

Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty 18945
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty 98943545

```
/var/log/mysqld.err
2022-04-14 23:08:02 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-04-14 23:09:03 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:10:03 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:11:03 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:12:03 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:13:03 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:14:04 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:15:04 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2022-04-14 23:16:04 29897 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
socket=/usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
skip-external-locking
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
symbolic-links=0
slow-query-log=1
long_query_time=10
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
expire_logs_days = 30
back_log = 1024
binlog_cache_size = 1M
ft_min_word_len = 4
interactive_timeout = 600
join_buffer_size =2M
max_connections = 250
max_heap_table_size = 1G
max_length_for_sort_data = 1024
open_files_limit = 8192
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
skip_external_locking
table_open_cache = 1024
tmp_table_size = 1G
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 32M
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 1
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 72000
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_log_file_size            = 384M
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 8
innodb_mirrored_log_groups      = 1
innodb_open_files               = 8192
innodb_read_io_threads          = 4
innodb_thread_sleep_delay       = 0
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
binlog_format=mixed
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
innodb_sort_buffer_size         = 64M
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp='ON'
```

show engine innodb status

```
=====================================
2022-04-15 11:31:32 7f789e076700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 23 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 27801 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 567 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 28368
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 25152
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 568006
Mutex spin waits 610594, rounds 1127018, OS waits 19398
RW-shared spins 141440, rounds 1168128, OS waits 5103
RW-excl spins 26360, rounds 603707, OS waits 526
Spin rounds per wait: 1.85 mutex, 8.26 RW-shared, 22.90 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 11550734631
Purge done for trx's n:o < 11550734620 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 197
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 14163, OS thread handle 0x7f789e076700, query id 1718880 59.9.133.89 softbuket init
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 11550734629, not started
MySQL thread id 14044, OS thread handle 0x7f789e035700, query id 1718877 localhost softbuket cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 11550734626, not started
MySQL thread id 2192, OS thread handle 0x7f78a407e700, query id 1718871 127.0.0.1 root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 11550734625, not started
MySQL thread id 2195, OS thread handle 0x7f78a4204700, query id 1718867 127.0.0.1 root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 11550716146, not started
MySQL thread id 2194, OS thread handle 0x7f789e1fc700, query id 1701319 127.0.0.1 root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 11550734628, not started
MySQL thread id 2193, OS thread handle 0x7f78a40bf700, query id 1718876 127.0.0.1 root cleaning up
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 10 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 11 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 12 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 13 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
377248 OS file reads, 14469 OS file writes, 12060 OS fsyncs
8.39 reads/s, 20798 avg bytes/read, 0.96 writes/s, 0.96 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 628, free list len 20580, seg size 21209, 29100 merges
merged operations:
 insert 51997, delete mark 5275, delete 1603
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 37845959, node heap has 30208 buffer(s)
11597.41 hash searches/s, 14342.20 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 1024333122697
Log flushed up to   1024333116908
Pages flushed up to 1024131855945
Last checkpoint at  1024131855945
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
10320 log i/o's done, 0.96 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 17582456832; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 723634
Buffer pool size   1048566
Free buffers       423735
Database pages     594623
Old database pages 219326
Modified db pages  47066
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1937589, not young 3809763
1297.90 youngs/s, 0.26 non-youngs/s
Pages read 591257, created 4170, written 4664
10.65 reads/s, 0.35 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 1 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 594623, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[132]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       33962
Database pages     50901
Old database pages 18780
Modified db pages  4446
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 84300, not young 230946
257.21 youngs/s, 0.04 non-youngs/s
Pages read 50352, created 600, written 381
1.26 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 50901, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       35287
Database pages     49579
Old database pages 18288
Modified db pages  3868
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 84463, not young 166353
256.08 youngs/s, 0.13 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49274, created 394, written 477
1.43 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49579, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       35822
Database pages     49034
Old database pages 18082
Modified db pages  3366
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 88382, not young 298952
195.38 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 48957, created 170, written 245
0.91 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49034, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       35317
Database pages     49560
Old database pages 18280
Modified db pages  4101
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 336859, not young 621710
0.43 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49259, created 372, written 432
0.43 reads/s, 0.17 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49560, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       34852
Database pages     50019
Old database pages 18453
Modified db pages  4327
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 90645, not young 160341
0.91 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49677, created 402, written 735
0.83 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 50019, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       35373
Database pages     49480
Old database pages 18254
Modified db pages  3947
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 379178, not young 423908
1.17 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49310, created 233, written 326
1.13 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49480, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       35583
Database pages     49292
Old database pages 18176
Modified db pages  3927
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 88054, not young 325863
194.38 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49010, created 351, written 322
0.74 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49292, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       36360
Database pages     48505
Old database pages 17885
Modified db pages  3674
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 86266, not young 286819
249.64 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 48345, created 211, written 308
0.43 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 48505, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 8
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       34659
Database pages     50198
Old database pages 18520
Modified db pages  4023
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 196745, not young 175363
0.61 youngs/s, 0.09 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49993, created 273, written 555
1.04 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 50198, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 9
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       35876
Database pages     48979
Old database pages 18065
Modified db pages  3955
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 89409, not young 192487
0.91 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 48630, created 408, written 281
0.39 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 48979, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 10
Buffer pool size   87381
Free buffers       35374
Database pages     49491
Old database pages 18256
Modified db pages  3672
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 327181, not young 637435
0.74 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49208, created 354, written 292
0.87 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49491, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 11
Buffer pool size   87380
Free buffers       35270
Database pages     49585
Old database pages 18287
Modified db pages  3760
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 86107, not young 289586
140.43 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49242, created 402, written 310
1.17 reads/s, 0.09 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 1 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49585, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[11]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
2 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 19507, id 140156157851392, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 249666, updated 120954, deleted 105604, read 8711970334
53.56 inserts/s, 25.17 updates/s, 23.83 deletes/s, 5920658.62 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: There are some variables that you do not name in this question, but are referred to in [Configuring Buffer Pool Flushing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-flushing.html)

Comment: Please post result of SELECT @@version;  just so we know what you are running.  Any SSD or NVME data storage?  With 18,000+ dirty pages, even if you could flush ONE per SECOND, you are looking at 5+ hours to be cleared of dirty pages.

Comment: I use MySQL 5.6.17-log - Source distribution

Comment: storage is HDD not SSD

Comment: I restart MySQL everyday, Before restart MySQL, Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty goes up to 2049483855 per day.

Comment: May I recommend going back to a default `my.cnf`, run it for (at least) one day, then change (AT MOST) one setting, and checking influence of that change the next day ? (buffer flushing is working here on MySQL 8.0.29, therefore another option might be to upgrade...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shutdown several minutes in the future, set `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` to a smaller percentage to help get the flushing done sooner.  Typically, people have it set to `75` or `90`.  Later versions of MySQL also have `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm`; this might be worth tweaking in advance, too.

On another note...  These should be limited to under 1% of RAM:

```
max_heap_table_size
tmp_table_size
```

**More**  (from changelogs)  What version are you using??

----- 2021-11-08 MariaDB 10.5.13 -- -- -----

[MDEV-26819](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26819) SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0 occasionally fails to trigger writes

----- 2021-02-22 MariaDB 10.5.9 -- Release Note -- -----

[MDEV-24537](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24537) - [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0](/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm) lost its special meaning

----- 2021-02-22 MariaDB 10.5.9 -- -- -----

[MDEV-24369](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24369) Page cleaner sleeps despite innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm being exceeded

----- 2021-02-22 MariaDB 10.5.9 -- -- -----

[MDEV-24537](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24537) innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0 lost its special meaning Merge Revision #02e7bff882 2021-01-06 10:53:00 +0100 - Merge commit '10.4' into 10.5

----- 2017-09-21 8.0.3 Release Candidate -- -- -----

InnoDB: Default values for configuration options that affect buffer pool preflushing and flushing behavior were modified:

The [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm](/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm) default value was changed to 10. The previous default value of 0 disables buffer pool preflushing. A value of 10 enables preflushing when the percentage of dirty pages in the buffer pool exceeds 10%. Enabling preflushing improves performance consistency.

The [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct](/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) default value was changed from 75 to 90. InnoDB attempts to flush data from the buffer pool so that the percentage of dirty pages does not exceed this value. The increased default value permits a greater percentage of dirty pages in the buffer pool.

----- 2014-11-25 MariaDB 10.0.15 -- -- -----

MDEV-6930 : Make innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct my.cnf variable a double

----- 2014-09-25 5.7.5 Milestone 15 -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

With [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) buffer pool flushing would not be initiated until the percentage of dirty pages reached at least 1%, which would leave up to 1% of dirty pages unflushed. (Bug #13029450, Bug #62534)

----- 2014-05-30 5.6.19 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

With [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0](/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) buffer pool flushing would not be initiated until the percentage of dirty pages reached at least 1%, which would leave up to 1% of dirty pages unflushed. (Bug #13029450, Bug #62534)

----- 2014-05-30 5.6.19 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

With [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0](/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) buffer pool flushing would not be initiated until the percentage of dirty pages reached at least 1%, which would leave up to 1% of dirty pages unflushed. (Bug #13029450, Bug #62534)

Comment: I use MySQL 5.6.17-log - Source distribution

Comment: I tried innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=1 and innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=3. it didn't work. also I tried to change max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size value to small. it also didn't work. Please help me..